# How to calculate size of children

Tags: flutter

If I want to implement Widget which sizes itself by sizing children, how do I do it?

Somehow I need to defer sizing until all children have figure out their size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom layout, using `CustomMultiChildLayout` or `CustomSingleChildLayout`.

Or, if this fits your needs, use `IntrinsicWidth`/`IntrinsicHeight` widgets.

Custom layouts are basically a `Stack` with only positionned children. Children pick their size and then the layout choose their position.
BUT it has a limitation. The layout size *can't* depend on it's children size.

`Instrinsinc` widgets are much simpler but also more limited. 
A use case would be to wrap a `Row` widget in `IntrincWidget`, to simulate the css `display: flex; align-items: stretch;`

If you need something more complex, you'll need to create your own `RenderObject`.
Yup, this is counter-intuitive.