# Get string size

Tags: string, flutter

I am wondering if there is some function that returns size of a string similar to the [size of NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669063/how-to-get-the-size-of-a-nsstring) in iOS?

Ex. We need to have some Widget at the bottom of screen where at first we should see only text but after user pulls that widget up, we would see more (something like bottom sheet). That starting height of the widget depends on the string.

Comment: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/after_layout might help you get what you want.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52659759/how-can-i-get-the-size-of-the-text-widget-in-flutter/52991124#52991124

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47283319/how-to-calculate-size-of-children

Answer (score 1):

Check out `CustomSingleChildLayout` it allows that the child get's layed out first then you can position it based on its size