# How to make this Text UI

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want  to make something like this UI in Text. (ignore picture) First Large Text and then other Information. Main problem is after 3rd line I can't start  it from under  the text.
so if anyone knows then help. Explain with any Example, this image is just for reference.

[image]

Comment: Are you just referring to `T` text widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this package `drop_cap_text: ^1.1.3` from pub.dev.
Same question is answered here
[drop cap letter in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54579979/16793736)

Comment: thank you  I will check it out

Comment: If it helped, accept and upvote the answer.