# How implement flow right layout in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How I can create a such widget:

FlowText(String text, child Widget);

with the following behaviour:

**Example 1**

```
some text <child>
```

**Example 2**

```
long long long long long long long
long long text             <child>
```

**Example 3**

```
long long long long long long long
long long long long long long long
text and long              <child>
```

**Example 4**

```
long long long long long long long
long long long long long long text
                           <child>
```

To my mind it's look like as a float right from the web (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float).

What I should use to implement this layout?

Thanks for help!

Comment: I think this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52659759/how-can-i-get-the-size-of-the-text-widget-in-flutter/52991124#52991124.

Comment: Yes, it's look very similar. Thanks! I will try to fit it.