# flutter how to get size of widgets before building

Tags: flutter

I'd like to fit multiple widgets into PageView,
if the page is full, I want to move to the next page.
So I'd like to get sizes of the widgets inside the page without building the widgets.

[This post](https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-widget-size-and-position-b0a9ffed9407) seems that it's required to build the widget first before getting the size.

For text, I can do it using [RenderParagraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52659759/how-can-i-get-the-size-of-the-text-widget-in-flutter).

Is it possible to get the size of custom widgets?
The widgets I want to get the size are basically text which we can tab each word.

Comment: That's VERY difficult to achieve.