# Simulate z-index effect on flutter

Tags: flutter, animation, stack

I have an animation inside a stack where part of the text content is hidden and only visible when the animated background passes above the item it self inside a stack, example code:

```
Stack(
  children: [
    Text('Something...'),
    AnimatedBackground(),
    AnimatedLightStick(),
  ],
)
```

The idea is that the light stick will move alongside the background (which is actually a foreground hiding the text) and reveal it because the background is painted using a gradient transparent in the middle, and it works well, [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlO5P.jpg) is an example. But I'd like to something more flexible an divide the `Text` widget in a way that only a word or half of the text remains behind the background while the other parte is aways visible, this would be easy to do simply playing around with css `z-index` property, I searched but I didn't find anything like that for flutter, is it possible to simulate this effect and bring only part of the text forward?

I tried to do something like this:

```
Stack(
  children: [
    Text('Hidden text...'),
    AnimatedBackground(),
    AnimatedLightStick(),
    Text('Visible text')
  ],
)
```

And kind of worked but since I need the text aligned in the middle o play with only a hidden word inside a phrase it would be a nightmare to adjust alignment (or not?)

Comment: z index is defined by a position in `children` list

Comment: @pskink Yes, I know, which why I'm trying to find a solution so I can maybe break my text and wrap inside some `ZIndex` widget maybe

Comment: i dont think that you can break your text into words easily: you would need to know the rendered width of every word which is not so easy to get

Comment: In case of breaking words and use the `z-index` I could use the `RichText` and set the index per each `TextSpan`, if there's no solution I would have to do something like you said, but it's hard to align then

Comment: Just found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60065737/6907051) solution which my help, I'll try to implement something based on the the text size

Comment: indeed, its not a piece of cake ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about your z-index based approach, but for Flutter you could make use of a [CustomClipper](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomClipper-class.html) to cut out a piece of your background.

The cutout piece needs to move along your light stick to create the intended effect. Check out [this example](https://dartpad.dev/109c65adf3d36e816d43c3f1c25c8365?null_safety=true) to find out, if it might be a suitable solution.