# How to Multi-column text in Flutter (text should be splitted in multiple widgets regarding to its length)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

**tl;dr**

How to split a string after it reaches the maxmimum height in its Text widget?

**My problem**

I'm new to Flutter, that's why it is possible that I did not see low hangig fruits.

What I want is, that a string of various length are splitted into an n-amount of styled Text widgets.

All in all it should look like a multi-column layout but also on dual screen devices (2 on the left side, 2 on the right side).

That's why I tought, the best idea is to split the text into a list of Text widgets that are constraint / limited by their maximum height.

**Question**

How to calculate the length of the text which fits into a column, that I can split it up?

**After that I think I know what I've to do**

I think after I know how to split the text everything else is straight forward.

**What I googled**

- [How can I get the size of the Text Widget in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52659759/how-can-i-get-the-size-of-the-text-widget-in-flutter)

**Sketch**

[image: App idea]

[image: Sketche]

Comment: Have not personally checked but [this suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52659759/ddg#56997641) might give you a hint.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't find a fully satisfactory solution yet, but this might be a workaround:

- Split your text on '\n'
- Map each line to a Widget
- Surround these widgets by a Wrap() widget

```dart
Wrap(
  direction: Axis.vertical,
  children: text.split("\n").map(
    (line) => Text(line),
  ).toList(),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

To split the text into a Multi-Line `Column`, you should simply wrap the `Text` widget inside an `Expanded` widget. `Expanded` widget will automatically change the line of the `Text` when it is at the end of the `Column`.

Comment: Do you meant "Muli-Column"? Multi-Line seems to be working out of the Box.

The Problem is that I have to have different Text widgets because of other circumstances.