# How to create a Text widget with exactly two lines of text in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to create a `Text` widget with exactly two lines of text even if text's length is too small or too large.

I can limit upper-bound of line count with `maxLines` like below:

```
Text(subtitle,
    maxLines: 2,
    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1?.copyWith(
        color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSurface,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
    )
)
```

I saw some answers where it is suggested to use a `SizedBox` to fix the height of content. I didn't feel right to hardcode this value.

I am looking for something like `lines` in Android's `TextView`. What else can I do to achieve this in Flutter?

**Update:**

From the help of comments & answers below, I am using following code now:

```
String withExtraNextLineCharacters(String text, int count) {
  String nextLineCharacters = "";
  for (int index = 0; index < (count - 1); index++) {
    nextLineCharacters += "\n";
  }
  return text + nextLineCharacters;
}
```

Comment: Try with Wrap and flexible widget.

Comment: @NehilKoshiya How can I specify line-count with Wrap or Flexible widget? If you have a working snippet of code, can you please add it as an answer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52659759/how-can-i-get-the-size-of-the-text-widget-in-flutter just pass text like `'\n'` into `_textSize` function

Comment: @Nagual Yes, appending text with `maxLines - 1` count of `\n` characters helps when `maxLines` is defined. Maybe you can add relevant part as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Text(subtitle+'\n',   
    maxLines: 2,
    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1?.copyWith(
        color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSurface,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
    )
)
```

the line break `\n` is a placeholder for 2 lines. The `subtitle`  shift them down... and the `maxLines` condition is cutting them away :-)

Comment: This is just as I wrote in comment above, `maxLines - 1` count of `\n` characters are enough. Is there any case where this assumption might fail?

Comment: I was thinking about an empty String ->  ''   in some frameworks the Text Box shrinks  in this case.  But i don't now exactly. I haven't tried.

Comment: One `\n` works for `maxLines: 2` even if text is empty, tested.