# How can i implement this Timeline Ui in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to implement a timeline ui like this  [image: TimeLine UI].

i tried by using listview builder and container inside transform widget for lines but i ended up getting large distance between those lines and circles and i can't find the correct angle.

is there any way to implement this ui. i need those circles clickable.

here is my implementation

```
return Scaffold(
  body: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50),
    child: ListView.builder(itemCount: 5,itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Column(
        children: [
          Align(alignment: index%2 == 0? Alignment.centerLeft : Alignment.centerRight,child: Container(width: 50,height: 50,child: CustomPaint(painter: CirclePainter(),))),
         index == 4 ? Container() : Transform.rotate(
            angle: index%2 != 0?-angle: angle,
            //-math.pi / 3.5
            child: Container(height: 50,width: 1,color: Colors.black,)
            // Container(
            //   height: 300,
            //   width: 1,
            //   color: Colors.black,
            //
            // ),
          )
        ],
      );
    },),
  ),
);
```

Heres what ive implemented(UI)
[image]

Comment: what is the angle value?

Comment: it can be dynamic based on height or a fixed value. it just need to connect the circles.

Comment: here's the angle i've used
`var height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
var width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
var dist = width - 100;
var mid = 400;
var angle = math.acos(dist/mid);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case, I think `ListView.separated` will be the better choice. Above answer doesn't work after changing screen width.

We need to get the width of `Chapter X` and circle (having radius 24). To get the `Text` size, we will use this.

```dart
Size _textSize(String text, TextStyle style) {
  final TextPainter textPainter = TextPainter(
      text: TextSpan(text: text, style: style),
      maxLines: 1,
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr)
    ..layout(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: double.infinity);
  return textPainter.size;
}
```

You can check original question and answer of [getting text size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60065737/10157127).

To draw lines I am using `CustomPainter`.

```dart
class DivPainter extends CustomPainter {
  int index;

  DivPainter({required this.index});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.grey
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 5;

    final path1 = Path()
      ..moveTo(0, 24)
      ..lineTo(size.width, size.height + 24);

    final path2 = Path()
      ..moveTo(0, size.height + 24)
      ..lineTo(size.width, 24);

    index.isEven
        ? canvas.drawPath(path1, paint)
        : canvas.drawPath(path2, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

I am using `ListView.builder` with `Stack[customPaint, widget]` for this solution

```dart
LayoutBuilder listview() {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) => Container(
        color: Colors.cyanAccent.withOpacity(.3),
        width: constraints.maxWidth,
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: itemLength,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final textWidth = _textSize("Chapter $index", textStyle).width;

            final painterWidth = constraints.maxWidth -
                ((textWidth + 24) *
                    2); //24 for CircleAvatar, contains boths side

            return SizedBox(
              height: index == itemLength - 1 ? 24 * 2 : 100 + 24,
              width: constraints.maxWidth,
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  /// skip render for last item
                  if (index != itemLength - 1)
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: SizedBox(
                        width: painterWidth,
                        height: height,
                        child: CustomPaint(
                          painter: DivPainter(index: index),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: index.isEven
                        ? MainAxisAlignment.start
                        : MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [
                      if (index.isEven)
                        Text(
                          "Chapter $index",
                          style: textStyle,
                        ),
                      const CircleAvatar(radius: 24),
                      if (index.isOdd)
                        Text(
                          "Chapter $index",
                          style: textStyle,
                        ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

> make sure of screenWidth > lineHeight*2, you can replace `100` with `constraints` dynamic value

You can check full snippet and run on [dartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=ed42bcd3f5d4b47d63255920874e38a2).
Also, if you are ok with not having precious positioning, you can use `ListView.separate`. You can find that inside [dartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=ed42bcd3f5d4b47d63255920874e38a2), Also make sure to remove extra spacing on `Path`. You can simply replace path with `drawLine`.

Answer (score 1):

i don't have a perfect solution for you, but you play around with my code (Use Stack instead of column)

**Output :-**

[image]

**Code :-**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TimelineExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const TimelineExample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TimelineExample> createState() => _TimelineExampleState();
}

class _TimelineExampleState extends State<TimelineExample> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50),
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 5,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              children: [
                Align(
                  alignment: index % 2 == 0
                      ? Alignment.centerLeft
                      : Alignment.centerRight,
                  child: Container(
                    width: 50,
                    height: 50,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.teal,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                index == 4
                    ? Container()
                    : Transform.rotate(
                        angle: index % 2 != 0 ? -0.3 : 0.3,
                        child: Container(
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: 48.0,
                            right: 48.0,
                          ),
                          height: 1,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                      ),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That's a good idea of using stack. but how can we figure the angle dynamically. is there any way to measure distances

Answer (score 0):

If you are not looking for specific UI then give a try with flutter package https://pub.dev/packages/timeline_tile

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).