# How to set dynamic height for Container Widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have text widget inside of container and if text is more than 4 lines this is overflowing to bottom of container. How can I set dynamic height for this container that will depends of text lines and avoid bottom overflow ? At the moment container have fixed value but if I remove this value it will disappear.

[image]

```
home component 

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Container (
   child:    SliverToBoxAdapter(
                        child: Container(
                          height: 180,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                          child: CustomeInfoWidget(
                            infoData: _infoDataList,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
) 
}
```

```
CustomeInfoWidget

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double _width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, left: 15, right: 15),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          PageView.builder(
            itemCount: widget._infoDataList.length,
            controller: _pageController,
            
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: _width - 10,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                      child: Text(widget._infoDataList[index].title,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                         
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Text(
                      widget._infoDataList[index].content,
                    
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
        
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Container height is dynamic by default and overflow can happen from parent widget. can you include [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: check edit post

Answer (score 0):

wrap your container with Singlechildscrollview or set overflow for your Text widget [Flutter - Wrap text on overflow, like insert ellipsis or fade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44579918/flutter-wrap-text-on-overflow-like-insert-ellipsis-or-fade)

Answer (score 0):

On your home component, you are fixing the height of `CustomeInfoWidget`. You can remove this.

```dart
 SliverToBoxAdapter(
   child: Container(
    //  height: 180,// remove this
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
          child: CustomeInfoWidget(
```

You can use `SliverFillRemaining` for `PageView`.

```dart
SliverFillRemaining(
  child:  PageView.builder(
```

Or you can wrap your text container with `Singlechildscrollview`  for inner scroll.

You can also calculate the text height and provide it.

[How can I get the size of the Text widget in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52659759/10157127)

Comment: ok but will disappear all content

Comment: Ok are you using custom-scroll view with pageView?