# scrollCotroller.animateTo not working in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:sizer/sizer.dart';

class ProjectFloorPlan extends StatefulWidget {
  ProjectFloorPlan(
      {Key? key,
      required this.selectedFloorPlan,
      required this.onChangeFloorplan})
      : super(key: key);
  final FloorPlan1? selectedFloorPlan;
  final Function onChangeFloorplan;
  @override
  State<ProjectFloorPlan> createState() => _ProjectFloorPlanState();
}

class _ProjectFloorPlanState extends State<ProjectFloorPlan> {
  final itemKey = GlobalKey();
  final scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    // selectedFloorPlan = widget.projectDetails?.property?.floorPlan?.floorPlan1;

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      key: const PageStorageKey<String>('controllerA'),
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      controller: scrollController,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          GoldenRoundedBox(
            onTap: () {
              Scrollable.ensureVisible(itemKey.currentContext!);

              scrollController.animateTo(
                0,
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 700),
                curve: Curves.easeIn,
              );
            },
            text: 'Floor plan 1BHK',
          ),
          GoldenRoundedBox(
            onTap: () {
              Scrollable.ensureVisible(itemKey.currentContext!);

              scrollController.animateTo(
                0,
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 700),
                curve: Curves.easeIn,
              );
            },
            text: 'Floor plan 2BHK',
          ),
          GoldenRoundedBox(
            onTap: () {
              Scrollable.ensureVisible(itemKey.currentContext!);

              scrollController.animateTo(
                0,
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 700),
                curve: Curves.easeIn,
              );
            },
            text: 'Floor plan 3BHK',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have 3 buttons which are horizontally scrollable. On pressing the button which is slightly visible in the UI it should scroll horizontally to make the button visible completely.

[image]

The buttons look like this. On pressing the third button which is slightly visible it must scroll to make it visible completely.
I have used

```
Scrollable.ensureVisible(itemKey.currentContext!);
```

and

```
scrollController.animateTo(
                            300,
                            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 700),
                            curve: Curves.easeIn,
                          );
```

But both of these are not working.
How to achieve this?

Comment: Can you provide a simplified widget that will reproduce the same error.  More about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I have updated the simplified widget @YeasinSheikh

Answer (score 1):

Firstly include `itemKey` that are you using on `

```dart
 body: SingleChildScrollView(
        key: itemKey,
```

`.animateTo` first positional argument takes an offset that will be used to scroll, you can increase the value like `100`

```dart
scrollController.animateTo(
  100,
  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 700),
  curve: Curves.easeIn,
);
```

Instead of hard-coded value you can use [`scroll_to_index`](https://pub.dev/packages/scroll_to_index) or [get the text width](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52659759/10157127) and provide there