# Right-Align a Widget at the end of a Text

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to reproduce this effect from WhatsApp :
[image: WhatsApp message]

As you can see, Here, the time *(in red)* is always at the end of the last line *(yellow)*, right-aligned *(white arrow)*.

If the time can't fit, it automatically goes to the line below.

I've managed to place a widget at the end of a line using RichText :

```
RichText(
        text: TextSpan(
          style: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 14.0,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          children: [
            const TextSpan(text: 'Hello'),
            WidgetSpan(
              child: Container(width: 10, height: 10, color: Colors.red,),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
```

But I can't find the solution to right-align the widget, as :

- RichText handle only one alignment at the time
- Adding a custom spacer between the TextPan and WidgetPan sets the WidgetPan to the next line
- I'm sure there's a better solution than calculating the remaining size to add padding.

Is there a good way to solve this problem?

EDIT :
I just found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52991124/9204504), by calculating the remaining size of the last line. I don't really like the method but it seems to work well.